# Laravel 4: How do I send a POST request as a JSON using browser plugin?

Tags: json, mongodb, api, laravel, laravel-4

Currently I am using Terminal to test my APIs as given below

```
   curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d      '{"list_id":"2","device_id":"987654322"}'    http://localhost/lemmeknw/public/index.php/api/v1/subscribe/subscribers
```

How can I implement it in realtime or how can I do it using browser?

My **Root**

```
    Route::group(array('prefix' => 'api/v1/subscribe'), function()
      {
      Route::resource('subscribers', 'SubscriberController');
      });
```

**Controller**

```
 public function store()
 {

       $newsubscriber = Input::json();
       DB::connection('mongodb')->collection('subscriptions')->insert(array(
                     '_id' => $subscriber->device_id,
                     'subscriptions' => array(array('list_id' => $subscriber->list1_id)),));

                $subscription = Subscription::where('_id',$subscriber->device_id)
                ->where('subscriptions.list_id',$subscriber->list1_id)->get();

            return Response::json($subscription);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using PHPStorm there is a built in RESTful tool which is extremely useful.  It can be found in the tools menu called "Test Restful Web Service"

There is also an app on the Chrome store (For free) called Postman that i also use to test API requests.